# Splines with logarithmic scale

Tags: interpolation, spline

Let's say I need to integrate the area under a curve, defined by an unknown function. I want to use several methods, being one splines. `InterpolatedUnivariateSpline` is pretty straightforward BUT works [very strangely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/460oL.png) when I want to have both axis in logarithmic scale. (No points outside the plot are provoking that creepy depression) I have tried to

1. Redefine my x and y values to logarithmic,
2. apply `InterpolatedUnivariateSpline`
3. trace the curve (xn, yn)
4. plot original data (x, y) and the splines (xn, yn)

Still I cannot get a curve that fits the data, but a straight line which is 10 orders of magnitude away. (Both x and y have len() = 14, they are small samples).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

# x and y read form csv
x_log = np.log10(x) ; fx_log = np.log10(fx) 
xn = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), num=1000)
f = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x_log, fx_log, k=3)
yn = f(xn)

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', xn, yn, 'r:', ms=3)
plt.xlabel(r'$\lambda$ ($\AA$)',size='12')
plt.ylabel(r'$\lambda F_\lambda (W/m^2)$ ',size='12')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[Outcome here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joxsN.png)

Should I maybe re-define xn and yn so that they also fit in the curve? I tried something like `xx = np.log10(xn) ; yy = np.log10(yn)` instead, also failing miserably.